# What doesn't count as character development?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, character-development

What doesn't count as character development?

I think most people assume by character development, you mean that a character becomes more mature, generally speaking, so let's say the character becomes less mature than before so therefore regresses into a worse person. Does that still count as character development?

Let's take an example. The character is kind, mature and respectful, but he turns into an insatiable violent beast who's the total opposite of that and does anything in his power to serve his own self-interest. Does that count as character development? What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, it counts as character development.

The reason behind character development is to create an interesting plot where things don't end up as they started -- because why bother with the story if nothing changed?

So, if a character develops, it's not important in which direction they go, it's just important that they *develop*.